# WooCommerce Checkout required fields issue with billing city field

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, checkout

Hya.

I have a woocommerce shop. Recently I got the problem with making required field in checkout billing form.

I Have maid this customization:

```
'city' => array(
    'label'        => __( 'City Name', 'woocommerce' ),
    'placeholder'  => __( 'City Name'),
    'required'     => true,
    'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field',     'validate-required' ),
    'validate'     => array( 'city' ),
    'autocomplete' => 'address-level2',
    'priority'     => 70,
),
```

in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-countries.php path,
as you see:

```
'required'     => true,
```

But NO asterisk is displayed (*) or `<abbr>` html tag is added to my form.

Any Idea about above question?

Regards.

Comment: Is it a priority clash? try changing 70 to 71.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without any guaranty** as it can depend on many things like your theme, third party plugins or customizations…

Official documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

> Instead of editing all the properties for this "city" checkout field, you should **just override the necessary ones**.

For example **you don't need to add** in your **`class`** property: `'address-field'` and `'validate-required'` as they are automatically added. Also the priority is already **`70`** for this billing field…

So you should try to keep only the properties that you need to change:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields', 100, 1 );
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

    $address_fields['city']['label']        = __( 'City Name', 'woocommerce' );
    $address_fields['city']['placeholder']  = __( 'City Name');
    $address_fields['city']['required']     = true;

    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code tested and works in WooCommerce.

This code will make city billing field this way:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Its great.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, at my site label and placeholder, changed but required function not change. Still show optional. How solve it?